# Advanced Custom Fields WYSIWYG More tag

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, read-more

Before describing the problem, let me first tell that I have already searched on google, also read the ACF documentation, support, even asked on their support forum but it's hard to get any kind of answer there.

So the thing is I have this wysiwyg on a custom post type I made where I have an item description, I really don't want to use the wp default editor because I designed a structure on the post to be more user friendly.

The problem comes when I add the  tag to the field, it will not work as the_content('Read More') for example, I have tried to find out but failed. I'm using the

```
<?php
global $more 
$more = 0;
?>
```

but then if I want to use like for example:

```
<?php the_field('the_field_name','Read More')?>
```

it will not show the More tag.

What can I do to display it?

Comment: ¿ **Where did you got** that `the_field` or `get_field` can have the second parameter of **"Read More"** ? - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/

Answer (score 2):

Simply go and apply the default filter:

```
// You´ll likely need a function that doesn´t echo/print the output to get this working
// without an error
echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_field( 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME', get_the_ID() ) );
```

Comment: Assuming this works, you can use get_field() to avoid the echo.

Comment: Hi kaiser, thanks for your answer, unluckily when I paste it into my code it doesn't show anything.

Comment: btw, of course I changed 'the_field_name' to my field name.

Comment: Hi kaiser, thanks again for trying to help me. Pasted the code, replaced the field name with mine, nothing happens :( Should I include the 
    <?php
    global $more;
    $more = 0;
    ?>

Comment: Hi again, I removed the $more, and I'm 100% sure I'm typing the field_name correctly. Nothing is shown.

Comment: I don't understand your question very well. Either if I put <?php echo get_field('the_field'); ?> or <?php the_field('the_field'); ?> will show the content properly.

Comment: kaiser, the function is `get_field( $field_name, $post_id );`, and `$post_id` is optional if inside the loop. & if some mod could clean up this comments would be nice :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but if you are looking for some flexibility when handling the content and the "read more", you can also use `get_extended`.

```
get_extended( get_field('the_field_name') );
```

This will return an array with the content separated in `main`, `extended` and `more_text`.

Read more here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_extended/